# Unwanted space at bottom of tabularx cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, spacing, tabularx

While trying to solve [another issue of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579023/layout-a-catalogue-of-exam-questions-in-latex), I encountered the following issue:

In a tabularx cell there is unwanted space getting inserted at the bottom when using the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\tikzset{inner sep=0mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \rule{2cm}{2cm} & \rule{2cm}{2cm} \\
    \hline
    \tikz{\node[fill,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};} & \tikz{\node[fill,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};} \\
    \hline
    Also get it & with text \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Picture:

[image: picture]

I suppose that space is for the stuff that belongs below the baseline of a text. Since I only want to put tikzpictures into the cells, how can I disable this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just omit the unnecessary `\hline` directives?

Comment: What do you mean by unnecessary? If I remove the `\hline`s the spacing is still there.

Comment: I mean unnecessary as in, "all that's needed to parse the table visually can be achieved *without* the horizontal lines". For that matter, the vertical lines are needed either.

Comment: The black boxes are just for demonstration purposes. It practice, the cells contain tikz pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is the depth of the strut.

Use `baseline`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\tikzset{inner sep=0mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \rule{2cm}{2cm} & \rule{2cm}{2cm} \\
    \hline
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};} &
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};} \\
    \hline
    Also get it & with text \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no need in the `tabular` environment for either the vertical lines or the interior horizontal lines. I suggest you load the `booktabs` package and use its `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` macros to create well-spaced exterior, i.e., top and bottom, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tabularx,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\tikzset{inner sep=0mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{XX}
    \toprule
    \rule{2cm}{2cm} & 
    \rule{2cm}{2cm} \\
    %\hline
    \tikz{\node[fill,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};} &
    \tikz{\node[fill,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};} \\
    %\hline
    Also get it & with text \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```